# Domain Access: Edit admin/domain/content/ display settings, filters etc

Tags: views, domain-access, nodes

I am using Drupal Commerce and Domain Access module and I wonder where I could be able to edit how page admin/domain/content is displayed. I would expect to find a View page which is utilised by this module to show content and to allow to add filters and fields.

I have got a multi-domain site with thousands of products and I need to filter content by manufacturer or other field and to assign all products with desirable keywoord to selected domains.

Am I missing anything? I have not found any corresponding View.
Thank you for an answer

Answer (score 0):

Domain Access does not provide a view like you want.
You could try the [Admin Views module](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_views) which overrides the standard content admin page with a view.
Also, [Domain Views module](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain_views) which integrates domain access with views.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Maybe it would suffice if there is a possibility to widen filter criteria form - beside Status, Type and Language I just want to add one or two more, to filter content by another field. I am not really good at programming, but I guess it could be accomplished somehow by editing domain_content.admin.inc like editing number of items to display?

Comment: You could write your own module which does the same as the the domain admin interfaces, than add your own customizations. Editing the files of the domain access module is probably not the ways to go as updating the module would override your edits.

Comment: I think this https://www.drupal.org/project/domain_vbo is exactly what I needed. Adding an action of setting domain affiliation to views bulk operation.

Answer (score 0):

The [Domain Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain) module for Drupal is for sorting and displaying content and themes/styles depending on the added system aware domains, which have to be covered, and only works with proper virtual host settings on server for incoming calls. It can achieve to give the visitor the feeling to be on two different places or at near but slidely different places. It is made for the cases where you definitely need a shared backend and content or design pool for two different domains but should not be considered for any case. It isn't as easy as it reads on the module project page. It needs further understanding how paths work in Drupal universe and can get broken on bigger updates. And you will have a hard time to teach a views view to be filtered different depending on incoming domain, even with [Domain Views Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain_views) at hand.

I sadly can not confirm to use the other recommendation [Admin Views modules](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_views) because it is too limited in its approach and its not true that views doesn't support overriding admin pages. It works very well and is mostly one of my first steps in a new Drupal installation. It even works great with the different tabs on the admin pages (like admin/content with the **files** or *comments* tab) and there are enough tutorials around explaining the path settings to setup and how it works. I hope I make noone upset here, but I think it is not true to say, that you need Admin View module for overriding admin pages like admin/content etc. Maybe there was a time when it was hard to achieve this with views allone, but in the meantime views has a lot of options to make it work and even with more options than Admin Views module provides out of the box and stucks there on its limits.